# how to show coverart in mediaplayer?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, media-player

I am new to phonegap and i'm building a media player for android using phonegap. I want to show the coverart for the song that is currently playing. How can i do it using phonegap?

Comment: why downvote for the question. I'm new to phonegap. my question may be  unclear or not appropriate but you could help me by just pointing it out wheres my mistake is instead of voting it down..

Comment: I can't speak for whoever downvoted you, but it may have been that they wanted to know http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a some code for writing album art in

```
http://getid3.sourceforge.net/source/write.id3v2.phps
// 4.14  APIC Attached picture
```

which can be useful if you want to play streaming media from your own server